# Mathematics for Game Development Book

Tags: mathematics, books

For someone with some background in maths, what is a good book about:

- The **core mathematics** for game development
- How these techniques are **applied to common problems** in game development

In particular, I am going to finish my degree in *Physics & Computer Science* this summer, and afterwards will start an MSc. in Games Development. So I am looking for an informative read over the summer.

I know that there are a lot of books about this out there. However, I am particularly looking for a book that does *not* waste 300 pages on re-explaining what Trigonometry, Vectors or Matrices are...

Is there any book that is written for people like me with some background in maths? Something that explains the less-obvious techniques and how to apply them to solving problems in game development? Topics could include for example 3D Maths, Collision Detection / Physics, AI.

Comment: Physics. Trigonometry, vectors and matrices. Looks like you've already got the most common things handled.

Comment: Well, let me explain... Yes, I could probably work out many game development problems myself, somehow. However, I'd prefer spending a few hours reading about the smart ways that others have come up with already, hence avoiding the reinvention of the wheel.

Comment: What is your background in game development? Are you very new to it?

Comment: Well, I would suggest you to start deving, and when you face a problem, just search the web and you'll find a good solution in math for it. IMHO this is better, because you're already applying the theory, so it "fix" on your head much better.

Comment: Far better than reading a book over the summer would be to develop a game over the summer. You'll find out what you need to focus more on and you'll get some experience. Also, my opinion is the MS is a waste.

Comment: "However, I am particularly looking for a book that does not waste 300 pages on re-explaining what Trigonometry, Vectors or Matrices are... " That doesn't exist. The audience for a game dev book are either first-time coders who think they can make a game, college students, or people who know stuff. The latter would never buy it, and the only people who don't need this intro material are the college students. And even some of *them* need it. So that's just not going to happen.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Yes, I'm very new to Game Development. I wrote a very simple 2D platformer using C++/SDL/OpenGL, and now I'm slowly trying to improve and expand on it. Also learning general concepts, i.e. what are standard solutions for game states, entity management, collisions, particles, that sort of thing. Online tutorials have brought me some way, however now they are mostly either already too easy or still too advanced (e.g. fluids). Also they are often not really best-practices.

Comment: So now I am at the point where I am playing around and advancing my gamedev-basics and 2D knowledge by myself, but would simultaneously like a book that teaches me all the fancy math I will need once I start doing 3D, more advanced stuff, and worrying about efficiency, e.g. in collision detection.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yeah, I was afraid of that... So what should I do? I was thinking about getting "Game Coding Complete" (new 4th edition just came out last month) anyway, so maybe I should go with that for now. And then fill in the more advanced mathematical concepts lateron (e.g. fluids, metaballs and all that awesomeness) using more specific (online) materials. I'm still at that stage where it's all very overwhelming, such a flood of stuff to learn... It seems very unstructured to me, i.e. in physics there mostly is a definitive order in which you learn topics. Gamedev seems to be quite messy?

Comment: @Ben: FYI: "fluids, metaballs and all that awesomeness" None of those have to do with game development. Certainly not in 99.999% of games that exist. I would not expect a game development book to cover fluid dynamics or metaballs. That's not to say that a game can't *use* them. But a book specifically about making games must be reasonably generic. And those kinds of things aren't generic.

Comment: @NicolBolas Well I would expect a book that focuses on advanced mathematics for game development to touch on such things. Metaballs maybe are a bad example, but at least fluids are something that I see everywhere these days. Maybe I should clear up that when I say "Game Development", I mean tripple-A PS3 etc games...

Comment: @Ben: No, you see *water*, which is a rendering effect done with triangles, textures, shaders, and particle systems. What you see in almost every case has nothing to do with fluid dynamics and physical modelling of water. Games in general do not require *advanced* mathematics. Even so-called AAA games don't usually require advanced math.

Comment: What math do you want to learn?  It's not like you can fit all the math that every game ever needs into a single book.  Are you looking to do physics?  You'd want to understand differential calculus, concepts like the Jacobian matrix, gradients, etc.  Are you looking to do 3D graphics?  Mostly going to be linear algebra, but also some ca

Comment: @NicolBolas See, I didn't know that. It makes an awful lot of sense though, since I have always been wondering how they do it. But what you notice is that I need a book to teach me all that stuff... My initial though-process was that e.g. a good 3D Graphics Programmers would need to have a very good understanding of the underlying mathematics (even if that does "only" include rendering and no actual Physics Simulations).

Comment: @seanmiddleditch Obviously you can't, but I was hoping you could fit all the maths that every college-student who wants to start game development would need in his first year into a single book. From a maths-book I was expecting the basics of Graphics, Physics, AI. However, what Nicol said earlier makes sense, the audience probably wouldn't be big enough to make this financially viable.

Comment: Take this book for example, http://www.amazon.com/Math-Primer-Graphics-Development-Edition/dp/1568817231/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_S_T1?ie=UTF8&coliid=I2VIYSUXEJ0RAD&colid=1KS5MC6UCM5FZ. This seems to be a good book. However, it just feels weird to buy a book where I am skipping the first 200 or so pages. So I was hoping for something that uses these 200 pages for something else.

Comment: Re-inventing the wheel is the best way to learn how the wheel was built in the first place.

Comment: @bobobobo Yes, but the crappy wheel you built yourself will be nowhere near the formula-1 wheels that are used these days ;)

Answer (score 6):

Ok, one thing I learned about *efficient* learning is, **don't just read**.  Program.  The problems with "just reading" are twofold:

1)  It's not very interesting, so progress can be slow

2)  The knowledge evaporates quickly, unless you do activities which make it stick

So get a good book *as a reference*, so you have something to refer to, **but above all start building a game** that will use basic physics.  Read when you encounter a problem you cannot solve on your own.  The book's material will be that much more interesting to you then.

Some great books I used when I was starting (even though I knew vector math etc) were:

1)  [3d math primer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0026A6CJ0)

2)  [Cg tutorial](http://developer.nvidia.com/node/76) - now available online for free.  I wouldn't recommend using Cg as a shading language at all these days, but the first few chapters are excellent, and the basic ideas of Cg (uniform parameters etc) have their analogs in other shading languages

3)  [Shirley's fundamentals of computer graphics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002K8Q9Q4) - contains concepts such as barycentric coordinates projection and rasterization

4)  [Real-time collision detection](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001086MGM) for collision detection

Comment: @Ben You'd probably want the more up-to-date 3d math primer: http://www.amazon.com/Math-Primer-Graphics-Development-Edition/dp/1568817231/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1335591252&sr=1-2

Comment: Wow, nice, thx so much for the nvidia link. I have heard of the 3D Math Primer, however, I really don't think I can make any use of the first 200 or so pages. Might just get it anyway, not sure.
@michael.bartnett Yeah, I noticed, all his links point to the kindle editions for some reason.

Comment: Spot on.  If you can program something, then you understand it, in depth, piece by piece.

Answer (score 1):

Commenters have given many helpful tips, but so far no one has actually answered my question (apart from one person saying there is no such book).

Well, I think [Mathematics for 3D Game Programming and Computer Graphics](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematics-Game-Programming-Computer-Graphics/dp/1435458869/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_S_T1?ie=UTF8&coliid=IT0W2GWHEWOH&colid=1KS5MC6UCM5FZ) seems to be about what I had in mind when I wrote my original question. It seems to have good reviews, so that might well be it. It even has a short chapter about fluids (just saying...)

Any feedback on this book?

Comment: I really like Eric Lengyel's book. Its first edition was a very useful textbook for me when I was a student, and I keep it next to my desk at work to this very day. I've referred to it so often that the binding is starting to wear out.